# How to invoke a property's method by property's name

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to call a property's method of an object through reflection. For instance,

```
var query = DataContext().SomeTable.Where(u => u.UserID.contains("P");
```

I've tried the following but no luck:

```
var query = DataContext().SomeTable.Where(u => u.GetType().GetProperty("UserID").Name.contains("P");
```

Which returns null. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx), not `Name`

```
((string)u.GetType().GetProperty("UserID").GetValue(u) ?? "").Contains("P")
```

The use of the [?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) here is just a safeguard to make sure that `Contains` doesn't throw an exception if `UserID` is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the value of `u`, then use `ToString` on it:

```
u.GetType().GetProperty("UserID").GetValue(u, null).ToString().Contains("P");
```

Of course it have be a little bit improved: check if `GetValue` do not return `null` etc.

*Note*: Remember that you can somewhere cache `PropertyInfo` obtained from `u.GetType().GetProperty("UserID")` so you won't have to call it every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer and suggestions.